# Sparql Query: Get all ?quote quoteBy ?text more than once

Tags: sparql

I'm trying to query my dataset so that I can find all quotations that are quoted by a distinct section of text more than once, but my query is not working.

I was thinking of something like this, but I'm not quite sure if I doing things right. Help is much appreciated.

```
SELECT ?s
WHERE {
       ?s a <http://scta.info/quotation> .
       ?s scta-rel:quotedBy ?section .
       FILTER (?section > 1) .
  }
LIMIT 1000
```

Here is an example of the the kind of information for each quotation type that is quote more than once. Notice this entry has is quoted by 3 different texts.

```
Property    Value
dc:title     Omnia per ipsum facta sunt, et sine ipso factum est nihil, quod factum est;
scta-rel:quotedBy   http://scta.info/items/lectio131
scta-rel:quotedBy   http://scta.info/items/lectio109
scta-rel:quotedBy   http://scta.info/items/lectio133
scta-terms:fromBiblicalBook http://scta.info/works/io
scta-terms:citation  io1_3
scta-terms:fromBiblicalChapter   1
scta-terms:fromBiblicalVerse     3
scta-terms:quotation     Omnia per ipsum facta sunt, et sine ipso factum est nihil, quod factum est;
scta-terms:quotetype    http://scta.info/quotetypes/biblical
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://scta.info/quotation
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to count the occurences of `?section`:

```
SELECT ?s
WHERE {
       ?s a <http://scta.info/quotation> .
       ?s scta-rel:quotedBy ?section .
  }
GROUP BY ?s
HAVING (count(?section) > 1)
```

This works by counting the sections for each `?s`.  `?section` must be unique for each `?s`because RDF graphs are sets of triples, no duplicates. 
Hence `?s scta-rel:quotedBy ?section .` and `GROUP BY ?s` only gives each `?section` once for each `?s`.